# git log from particular sha to head

Tags: git

I have a script:

```
for sha1 in $(git log <BRANCH> --format=format:%H --no-merges)
do 
    if [ "$sha1" == "<TRAGET_SHA>" ]
    then 
        break
    fi
    echo $sha1
done | tail -r
```

What it does is from a particular `BRANCH` lists all no merge sha's (in 'reverse' order) starting from `TRAGET_SHA` to `HEAD`.

I spent 30 minutes trying to achieve the same with git command directly with no success.

Is this possible to achieve? How?

Comment: `git log <target_sha>..<branch> --reverse --no-merges --format=format:%H`?

Comment: @chepner thanks a lot, this works. I was trying something of the sort `git log <branch> <target_sha>..HEAD` and it was not working